# Can I access context object in decorator over django view

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, python-decorators

I have multiple django views to which I want to add some context based on their response and status code. Right now I have a code that look something like this:

```py
def my_decor(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if response.status_code == 200:  # It will be changed to manipulate 2XX reponses only
            new_data = foo()
            response.context['some_new_data'] = new_data
        return response
    return wrapper


@my_decor
def view1(request):
    # some logic
    context = {'some_data': 'some_value'}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)


@my_decor
def view2(request):
    # more logic
    return render(request, 'another_template.html')
```

So, bassically, I want to create decorator, that can be used with views that attach context on return and with those that don't.
Right now I get `AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'context'`.
What am I doing wrong?

Python 2.7.13 and Django 1.7.11

Comment: What advantage or use you wish to obtain by adding something to an HTTP response?

Comment: It will be conveniet not to change views that have ```return render(request, 'tmp.html')```, but to add decorator to them, so their HttpResponse will have context that I need to access in template. The easiest way would be to put ```foo()``` into every function and change every return to ```return render(request, 'tm.html', context)```

Comment: *"so their HttpResponse will have context that I need to access in template"* .... The `HttpResponse` is something which has the *"rendered output"*, ie, the result of `render(request, 'some_template.html', context)`. In that cases, you can't ***manipulate*** the context data

Comment: Moreover, I would recommend using the CBV so that you will have more control over the context data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `func(*args, **kwargs)` in your decorator, you have rendered the template, and it is too late to change the template.

You could switch to [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects), which allows you to modify the context before the template is rendered. Access the context using the response's `context_data` attribute.

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

@my_decor
def view1(request):
    # some logic
    context = {'some_data': 'some_value'}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

In your decorator, change `response.context` to `response.context_data`:

```
    if response.status_code == 200:  # n.b. this is only for 200 responses, not 2XX as you say in your comment
        new_data = foo()
        response.context_data['some_new_data'] = new_data
```